# String confusion in Javascript with regard to dynamically loading a path

Tags: javascript, dynamic-import

I've encountered something very peculiar in Javascript, which I can't explain.  Simply put, I'm building a dynamic Button component in React in which one can optionally pass in the path of an icon file.

This approach works perfectly:

```
const image = require('../styling/assets/images/search-icon.svg');

<button className='button' onClick={props.handleButtonClick}>
  <img className='button-icon' src={image} />
  <p>{props.label}</p>
</button>
```

But it fails if I change the first line to these two:

```
const path = '../styling/assets/images/search-icon.svg';
const image = require(path);
```

In this second case I get this error: `Error: Cannot find module '../styling/assets/images/search-icon.svg'`

Fundamentally the two approaches seem equivalent to me but apparently not.

Why does the 2nd approach fail?

Answer (score 0):

According to the internet: "require is resolved during packaging not during runtime".

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391

Answer (score 0):

According with MDN docs:

> The import statement cannot be used in embedded scripts unless such
>   script has a type="module". Bindings imported are called live bindings
>   because they are updated by the module that exported the binding.

More information here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import